# How could you describe a big truck taking up most of the space of a narrow street?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

I want to put a clear image of a huge, rusty, sheep-carting truck taking up half of a narrow street street.

"Dominated" does not sound right to me, I am looking for a word to replace "taking up."

"A huge, rusty, sheep-carting truck was _____ the narrow, suburban street."

Comment: Welcome to EL&U, but this is not a writing workshop. I strongly encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help] for a better understanding of how Stack Exchange works, and the kinds of questions that are well-suited to our format.

Comment: Excuse me, but I didn't for once assume it was. What I have asked for is another word for, which comes under word choice and word usage. I found your comment to be quite rude. I have asked these questions before and I have also taken note to see hundreds of questions similar to mine.Don't try and mask your rudeness with a welcome.

Comment: You could say that the truck is *hoarding* the road; while not strictly literal, it's not uncommon to use hoarding to basically mean, "taking something all for yourself and not leaving any for anyone else".

Answer (score -1):

I've frequently seen the word *monopolize* used in reference to space.